# How to stack a level in a bar chart?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to build a stacked bar chart from a 2x2 dataframe. I'm using `ggplot2 1.0.0`. Unfortunately, the column with data for the `B` level only shows one colour, instead of two.

```
df <- data.frame(x1 = rep(c("A","B"), each = 2), x2 = c(75.0, 25.0, 50.0, 50.0))


fig1 <- ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x1, y = x2)) + geom_bar(aes(x1, fill = x2), stat = "identity") + xlab("") + ylab("%") + ggtitle("df")
fig1 + geom_text(aes(label = x2), vjust = -0.8, colour = "white")
```

The code produces the following graph: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjdBK.jpg

Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you! Would you add this as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used a continous scale for fill, so two 50 values have the same colour. You could use a discrete scale like this:

```
ggplot(transform(df, var = as.factor(1:2)), 
       aes(x = x1, y = x2, fill = var)) + 
   geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```